# How extract Width and Height pixel value from a React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to get the Height and Width from a React component to use in a resize image function.

I'm working in a react app and I have a component called Canvas that receives 4 image components and distribute them through the screen forming a square.

To do this, right now, I created a function that resizes those images in order to fit them properly.

The problem is that right now the Max Width and Height of those images are calculated with a hard-coded parameter of my current screen.

I need to know the Width and Height of this Canvas component so I can pass this parameter and make a dynamic function.

I tried using IDs, Refs and even tried the "calc" function from CSS and I just can't receive that information...

The Resize function

```
var resize = function (maxh, maxw, acth, actw) {
  const ratio = maxh / maxw;
  if (acth / actw > ratio) {
    // height is the problem
    if (acth > maxh) {
      actw = Math.round(actw * (maxh / acth));
      acth = maxh;
    }
  } else {
    // width is the problem
    if (actw > maxh) {
      acth = Math.round(acth * (maxw / actw));
      actw = maxw;
    }
  }
  return({ height: acth, width: actw });
};

export default resize;
```

The Component that I need to use the resized information

```
function EnhancementTaskItem(props) {
  const jsonId = props.jsonId
  const maxWidth = 900
  const maxHeight = 380
  const actualWidth = 1800
  const actualHeight = 760
  const size = resize(maxHeight, maxWidth, actualHeight, actualWidth)
  const image = `https://via.placeholder.com/${actualWidth}x${actualHeight}.png?text=${jsonId}+${props.method}`
  return (
    <Box style={{ margin: "1rem" }}>
      <Card>
        <CardActionArea >
          <CardMedia
            style={{ height: size.height, width: size.width }}
            image={image}
          />
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The Component that I need to extract the Height and Width

```
class EnhancementTask extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" minHeight='calc( 100vh - 8rem )'>
        <EnhancementTaskItem jsonId={json.id} method="photo" />
        <EnhancementTaskItem jsonId={json.id} method="document" />
        <EnhancementTaskItem jsonId={json.id} method="document w/ photo" />
        <EnhancementTaskItem jsonId={json.id} method="b/w" />
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

export default EnhancementTask;
```

Comment: So your question is how to get the actual size of an element - a `div`, an `img` etc?

Comment: From React Components, I tried with tags and I didn't manage to do that. Than I read [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/tech-blog/react-size-position) and started to think that It wouldn't be easy as in a normal web application...